# SSRS - how to filter or hide visibiltiy based on a single category of a grouped column

Tags: reporting-services

I am stuck on a issue that sounds not that complicated but did not find any proper solution so far. I know a bit about filtering and hide visibility but this one seems tricky to me.

I have a matrix showing the totals of different booking "systems" as grouped rows and a grouped column called "type" that shows me the two categories "bookings" and "errors".

What I want to achieve is whenever the certain category "errors" has no value, it shall hide or filter out this row.

[design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlsqY.jpg)
[preview mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DN0t.jpg)

I tried to filter and hide visibility but it always takes the total of the whole group "type" not the total of its category "errors".

Do you see a way to do so on "errors" only?

Many thanks in advance.

Best regards

Alex

Comment: can you add some sample data to realize your req. It shall be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working as you would expect is due to your column grouping that your error count is in. It's counting all the types, not just errors.

I believe it would work for you if you just check the Error types.

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!type.Value = 'Errors', Fields!attempts.Value, 0)) > 0, False, True)
```

This will `SUM` the `Attempts` where the `Type = 'Errors'` and hide if zero.

Comment: Hi @Hannover Fist, Thank you very much. Appreciate your proper answer. This solved my problem. Best regards. Alex